# c++ UVA 579 - ClockHands wrong answer

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve this question but the system keep giving me "wrong answer". I checked other people's solution and I'm sure my algorithm is correct. Can anyone help me with it? thanks a lot.
Question: **[UVA 579 ClockHands](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=520)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int hour, minute;
    float hour_degree, minute_degree;
    float total;
    while(scanf("%d:%d",&hour, &minute) == 2)
    {
        if( hour == 0 && minute == 0)
            break;
        minute_degree = minute * 6;
        hour_degree = hour * 30 + float(minute / 2);
        total = fabs(hour_degree - minute_degree);
        if(total > 180)
            total = fabs(360 - total);
        printf("%.3f\n", total); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I compiled your program with g++4.4 and the output is exaclty as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spotted a bug here

```
hour_degree = hour * 30 + float(minute / 2);
```

You are doing integer division, and it goes wrong if `minute` is odd number. It should be

```
hour_degree = hour * 30 + float(minute / 2.0);
```

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot! So do I still need to convert the number to float if I use "minute/2.0"??

Comment: You can use `(minutes / 2.0f)` without explicit cast. The parentheses is not necessary but for the sake of readability.